# Mary knows about his being Superman

Tags: gerunds

Mary knows about his being Superman.

Is that sentence right?

Sorry, I've overlooked a certain context.

Okay, in order to prevent this sentence from being vague, Please see the above sentence again.
Plus, the context is like this.

> Mary knows he is Superman.

But now I want to paraphrase that sentence in a different way like using "know about" and using Gerunds.

Comment: This question needs more context.  Are you only asking if it is grammatically correct?  Do you have a specific question about why it is correct or not?

Comment: This question is really vague, which is why you wouldn't ever use it. Who is "he" -- is it the same person as "his being", or a different person?

Comment: @FeliniusRex Sorry, I've revised my question. Please look at it again.

Comment: Ok, this works. These kinds of sentences often have a *that* before *he*, but it works both ways.